# how can i embed ppt in webview to run on android

Tags: android, powerpoint, android-webview

i want to create an android application in which i have to run ppt which will be present in sdcard. So far i have got to know that the only way to run the ppt is either calling different applications which deal with this or embed that in webview. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot embed ppt, doc, excel etc in a `Webview` in android. Those are MS Office formats. You cannot even do that on a desktop pc with firefox/chrome.

**EDIT**
If the ppt is online you can use google docs to convert your document to html and than display it:

```
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://myurl.com/mySlide.ppt");
```

If the ppt is on SD card, either:
a) Open it with default phone application. See [How to use an intent to open a ppt with DataViz's Documents To Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132931/how-to-use-an-intent-to-open-a-ppt-with-datavizs-documents-to-go)
b) you need to convert it to html beforehand. There are many online/offline tools for that. Google "ppt to html converter"

Comment: ohhh... ok... well then how can i achieve this i followed the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468621/android-load-pdf-pdf-viewer

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (depending if you no need your PPT file into the SDCard) is embed a PPT in a WebView using an iFrame like Office Web Apps or GoogleDocs.

I tested and works, but this options requires to have the PPT file into servers of Office Web Apps or GoogleDocs.